# What type of Groovy construct is Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have gone through Jenkins documentation but unable to find out what kind of construct exactly is a pipeline. It is neither a class nor a function or any data structure given in Groovy documentation. As a result I can't compile and run a pipeline like:

```
         $ groovy mypipeline.groovy
```

Comment: Pipeline is a dsl based on groovy.  it couldn't be called from groovy command line. However you could call groovy classes and scripts from pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for your response daggett. It helped me google and found this great article. https://objectcomputing.com/resources/publications/sett/november-2016-the-power-of-groovy-dsls